# How to convert this to a for-loop with an output to CSV

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, finance

I'm trying to put together a generic piece of code that would:

1. Take a time series for some price data and divide it into deciles, e.g. take the past 18m of gold prices and divide it into deciles [DONE, see below]

   ```
   date        4. close   decile                
   2017-01-03    1158.2       0
   2017-01-04    1166.5       1
   2017-01-05    1181.4       2
   2017-01-06    1175.7       1
            ...     ...
   2018-04-23    1326.0       7
   2018-04-24    1333.2       8
   2018-04-25    1327.2       7
   [374 rows x 2 columns]
   ```
2. Pull out the dates for a particular decile, then create a secondary datelist with an added 30 days

   ```
    #So far only for a single decile at a time
    firstdecile = gold.loc[gold['decile'] == 1]
    datelist = list(pd.to_datetime(firstdecile.index))
    datelist2 = list(pd.to_datetime(firstdecile.index) + pd.DateOffset(months=1))
   ```
3. Take an average of those 30-day price returns for each decile

   ```
   level1 = gold.ix[datelist]
   level2 = gold.ix[datelist2]
   level2.index = level2.index - pd.DateOffset(months=1)
   result = pd.merge(level1,level2, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)

   def ret(one, two):
     return (two - one)/one

   pricereturns = result.apply(lambda x :ret(x['4. close_x'], x['4. close_y']), axis=1)
   mean = pricereturns.mean()
   ```
4. Return the list of all 10 averages in a single CSV file

So far I've been able to put together something functional that does steps 1-3 but only for a single decile, but I'm struggling to expand this to a looped-code for all 10 deciles at once with a clean CSV output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First append the close price at `t + 1 month`  as a new column on the whole dataframe.

   ```
   gold2_close = gold.loc[gold.index + pd.DateOffset(months=1), 'close']
   gold2_close.index = gold.index
   gold['close+1m'] = gold2_close
   ```

   However practically relevant should be the number of trading days, i.e. you won't have prices for the weekend or holidays. So I'd suggest you shift by number of rows, not by daterange, i.e. the next 20 trading days

   ```
   gold['close+20'] = gold['close'].shift(periods=-20)
   ```
2. Now calculate the expected return for each row

   ```
   gold['ret'] = (gold['close+20'] - gold['close']) / gold['close']
   ```

   You can also combine steps 1. and 2. directly so you don't need the additional column (only if you shift by number of rows, not by fixed daterange due to reindexing)

   ```
   gold['ret'] = (gold['close'].shift(periods=-20) - gold['close']) / gold['close']
   ```
3. Since you already have your deciles, you just need to [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the deciles and aggregate the returns with `mean()`

   ```
   gold_grouped = gold.groupby(by="decile").mean()
   ```

Putting in some random data you get something like the dataframe below. `close` and `ret` are the averages for each decile. You can create a csv from a dataframe via [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

```
              close       ret
decile                       
0       1238.343597 -0.018290
1       1245.663315  0.023657
2       1254.073343 -0.025934
3       1195.941312  0.009938
4       1212.394511  0.002616
5       1245.961831 -0.047414
6       1200.676333  0.049512
7       1181.179956  0.059099
8       1214.438133  0.039242
9       1203.060985  0.029938
```

Comment: Please tell if that's what you needed. If not I'll try to elaborate. Otherwise I'd be thankful if you'd accept the answer.